# Is there a general uniques counting function?

Tags: function, matlab

By general, I mean it can count the different elements in the input given it is either a list of numbers (or other atoms), a list of vectors or a list of matrices.

Example: given a list of row vectors of length 3:

```
x = [1 1 1; 1 0 1; 0 1 1; 1 0 1; 1 1 1; 1 0 1];
```

the expected outcome should be:

```
[1 1 1] --> 2
[1 0 1] --> 3
[0 1 1] --> 1
```

returned in e.g. two lists. I know about the `count_uniques` function, but it deals with non-array inputs only, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `unique`. If the input is an array use `unique(X,'rows')`.

If you want a universal function you can do:

```
function varargout=universal_unique(X);
   if(size(X,2)==1)
      [varargout{:}]=unique(X);
    else
      [varargout{:}]=unique(X,'rows');
   end
end
```